# I need to pass an object of class from Xaml File

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, enums

I am implimenting a class having two variables and initializing it in xaml and pass its object to ModelView and then publishing this object it .

when I doing it I am, getting an exception at this line

> modelproperty:ModelProperty bMode="enums:Modes.TType"
>   dStyle="enums:StyleModes.PType" />

Exception

> "{"'Provide value on
>   'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an
>   exception.' Line number '217' and line position '20'."}"

Xaml File

```
 <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="PointsItem" Content="Points" RibbonStyle="Large"  Command="{Binding StyleCommand}" 
 <dxb:BarButtonItem.CommandParameter>

<modelproperty:ModelProperty bMode="enums:Modes.TType" dStyle="enums:StyleModes.PType" />

</dxb:BarButtonItem.CommandParameter>
</dxb:BarButtonItem>
```

Cs file

```
public class ModelProperty
    {
        public Modes bMode { get; set; }
        public StyleModes dStyle { get; set; }

        public ModelProperty(Modes _bMode, StyleModes _dStyle)
        {
            bMode = _bMode;
            dStyle = _dStyle;

        }  

        public ModelProperty()
        {
            //To be implemented
        }
    }
```

View Model

```
 this.DrawStyleCommand = new DelegateCommand<ModelProperty>(param =>
            {
                var xModelProperty = param as ModelProperty;
                eventAggregator.GetEvent<StyleChangedEvent>().Publish(xModelProperty);
            });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using `bMode="{x:Static enums:Modes.TType}"` instead of `bMode="enums:Modes.TType"`. HTH

Answer (score 1):

```
<modelproperty:ModelProperty bMode="enums:Modes.TType" dStyle="enums:StyleModes.PType" />
```

This would typically work if you are doing it on a UIElement/Control where type converters will convert string to the corresponding type. Since you are doing it on a normal class it will consider `"enums:Modes.TType"` as a string rather than an `Enum` of Value `Modes.TType`. Thats why you are getting the exception.

You should consider doing this in the code behind, as you are just going to initialize this object.You can very well do it in the code behind constructor. But if you still insist on doing it in XAML try using [TypeConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx)